# COMError: (-2147024894, 'Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Tags: python, com, activex, comtypes

I am using Python to open a COM Object to load some stuff from factset.
If I do so I get to following error:

> COMError: (-2147024894, 'Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Which means "The system cannot find the specified file".

I tried many different ways to give a file and path...

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject                
fs = CreateObject("FactSet.FactSet_API.1")

tempFile = r'C:\Temp\test.xls'

fs.RunApplication('Downloading',tempFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the files existance first?

```
import os    
tempFile = r'C:\Temp\test.xls'
if not os.path.exists(tempFile):
    # handle the case here
else:
    # then proceed with your code
```

Alternatively, to handle at the exception level in COMtypes
You can handle the issue using COMError, but checking for the file in the above manner is probably one of the easier ways...